# Xamarin Android TapGestureRecognizer not firing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

So have following xaml that has a code behind method named `HotelReservationOption_Tapped` that does not fire in Android only. I am using version 18.3.0.40 for `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SFListView`.

Using Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.560

```
    <StackLayout x:Name="ActiveList" IsVisible="{Binding IsActiveListVisible}" Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <syncfusion:SfListView AutoFitMode="Height" ItemsSource="{Binding ReservationListActive}" SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,9,20,14" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="6">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding HotelName}" TextColor="{StaticResource LabelColor}" FontSize="18"/>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="9">
                                                <Image Source="calendarPageEmpty1"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding HotelName}" TextColor="{StaticResource LightGrey2}" FontSize="14"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Image HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Source="dots.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="HotelReservationOption_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding HotelID}"/>
                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="1" Color="{StaticResource LineColor}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        </syncfusion:SfListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Is anyone aware of any bugs specific to Android for this control?

Comment: I test with `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView` 18.3.0.47 version and `Xamarin.Forms` is `4.6.0.1141` the tapped event couldd be executed. Here is running GIF.https://imgur.com/a/cVPuHzq

Comment: Did you try on Android? Works fine for me in iOS

Comment: Yes,I tried it in Android, it worked, link of running results in above comment